# PostgreSQL: Update does not work from one table to another: Query does not return results

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, foreign-keys

What I'm trying to do:

Table A has a column A2 with many different values, each of them occurring one or several times. With a foreign key in column A4 table A points to another table B. This table contains data (in column B2) specificly about each of the values in A2. Hence I want to update another column A3 in table A with these data. Left join didn't work because it only one occurrence of the values in A2 would be matched with the data, not all.

I tried it then with the following:

```
UPDATE
table_A
SET
column_A3 = table_B.column_B2
FROM
table_B
WHERE
table_A.column_A4 = table_B.column_B1
```

However, the script returns the following:

"Query failed: Query does not return results"

This problem might be covered already somewhere, but I couldn't make sense of the suggestions. Would be great if someone could offer some help, thanks a lot!!

best, cuezumo

edit: 
this is how the code actually looks:

```
 UPDATE
"${projectKey}_stack_dr_pa"
SET
"rideshare_startdate" = "${projectKey}_accepted_rideshares"."start"
FROM
"${projectKey}_accepted_rideshares"
WHERE
"${projectKey}_stack_dr_pa"."rideshare_id" = 
"${projectKey}_accepted_rideshares"."rideshare_id"
```

Comment: When you run a join of those two tables, do you get any results?  The error message seems to be saying that no, there are no records returned from that update join.

Comment: Yeah, I joined them already and everything worked like usual.

Comment: That is not a standard Postgres error message. Sounds as if your SQL client can't properly handle an UPDATE statement. Which tool do you use to run the statement? And how do you run it there?

Comment: I use Dataiku which offers the option to edit datasets with several tools, one of them PostgreSQL. 
I just added the code with the original table- and column-names above.

Comment: Apparently this Dataiku tool expects that the statement you run returns a result. Sounds like a bug in that tool. From a Postgres point of view that statement is perfectly fine